# <f:viewParam> called again on first AJAX request

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, viewparams

I'm using JBoss Wildfly 8.2.0 and noticed that `<f:viewParam>` is called twice on my page:

- The first time is when I access my page with the given param in the URL
- The second time is upon the first AJAX request I make from that page

Bean:

```
@Named
@javax.faces.view.ViewScoped
public class MessageBean implements Serializable {

    private String message;
    private int count;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("setting message");
        this.message = message;
    }

    public void increment() {
        this.count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html ...>
<html ...>
    <f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="message" value="#{messageBean.message}" />
    </f:metadata>
    <h:head>
        <title>Message</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <h:outputText value="#{messageBean.message} (#{messageBean.count} time(s))" />
            <h:commandButton value="increment">
                <f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{messageBean.increment}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

I don't understand why AJAX requests are triggering the `<f:viewParam>` and why only the first one.

Comment: It also happens to me with Mojarra 2.2.10 + Tomcat. I've found this related question (which doesn't explain the behaviour BTW): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21222348/using-fviewparam-with-required-attribute-and-commands

Comment: Thanks for the link. This is really weird because I thought `<f:viewAction>` would have had the same problem but it doesn't. So I think this is a bug in mojarra. If only somebody (@BalusC ?) could confirm...

Comment: [Process f:viewParam only on page load](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23903351/1391249).

Comment: @Tiny: Yes! I had that answer in mind while searching for a dupe, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by [statefulness](http://jdevelopment.nl/stateless-stateful-jsf-view-parameters/) of the `<f:viewParam>`.

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has solved this with its [`<o:viewParam>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/viewParam).

#### See also:

- [Process f:viewParam only on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903351/process-fviewparam-only-on-page-load)